# Install an application so that it can be launched from the terminal

Tags: installation, command-line, firefox

I had to update my Firefox from ver 3 (i.e. the one that Ubuntu 10.04 ships with) and move it to Firefox 7.
So firefox gave a tar.gz file to extract the browser from. I ran `sudo apt-get remove firefox`, and then extracted the contents of the tarball to `/opt/`. But when i type the command `firefox` in the terminal it responds by saying `firefox not installed`. I am now using a launch shortcut to open firefox, but what i want to know is
**How can I install the application so that I can open it from the terminal?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The programs to be executed are searched in the directories defined in the environment variable PATH.  You can see what you have defined using:

```
$ cat $PATH
```

Assuming you have the executable available in /opt/firefox/bin, then you can do:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/firefox/bin
```

To make permanent, you have to add that line it in your ~/.bashrc.

Comment: How will I add this line to the `./bashrc` ?. I have tried adding the complete line but it does not work.

Comment: Note the file is .bashrc, not bashrc.  It has to be in your home directory.  For what it is worth, you have to omit the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

For a single user:

```
ln -s /path/to/firefox ~/bin/firefox
```

For all users:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```